# What is .NET Core doing to the Key value returned by my custom ITicketStore implementation before it's sent to the browser?

Tags: asp.net-core, session, session-cookies

I implemented my own ITicketStore implementation in .NET Core which handles storing session cookies in a redis database. My keys are a simple guid:

```
    public async Task<string> StoreAsync(AuthenticationTicket ticket)
    {
        var log = new StringWriter();
        var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        var key = "MyCustomCache"+ guid.ToString();
        await RenewAsync(key, ticket);
        return key;
    }
    public Task RenewAsync(string key, AuthenticationTicket ticket)
    {
        var options = new DistributedCacheEntryOptions();
        var expiresUtc = ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc;
        if (expiresUtc.HasValue)
        {
            options.SetAbsoluteExpiration(expiresUtc.Value);
        }
        byte[] val = SerializeToBytes(ticket);
        _cache.Set(key, val, options);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
```

However in the browser when I check the value of the cookie it seems to be encoded/encrypted somehow (rather than the guid I generated):

[image: screenshot of guid]

When the cookie is passed to my application I notice that its been transformed back to the original value I created in StoreAsync:

```
public Task<AuthenticationTicket> RetrieveAsync(string key)
{
    // Key passed in here will not be the value in the image above. Instead it will be what was 
    // generated in StoreAsync
    AuthenticationTicket ticket;
    byte[] bytes = null;
    bytes = _cache.Get(key);
    ticket = DeserializeFromBytes(bytes);
    return Task.FromResult(ticket);
}
```

What exactly is .NET Core doing to my keys to encrypt/encode the key? Will this affect my ability to load balance my application? I know that in the default session storage mechanism .NET Core encrypts the session cookies using a dynamic key per machine.

Comment: I just wrote a blog post about the TicketStore and how it works in ASP.NET Core  https://nestenius.se/2024/01/22/improving-asp-net-core-security-by-putting-your-cookies-on-a-diet/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The authentication cookie is being encrypted with the default data protection.

Here is where the key is added to the cookie ([source](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/f2e6e6ff334176540ef0b3291122e359c2106d1a/src/Security/Authentication/Cookies/src/CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs#L308)):

```cs
if (Options.SessionStore != null)
{
    if (_sessionKey != null)
    {
        await Options.SessionStore.RemoveAsync(_sessionKey);
    }
    _sessionKey = await Options.SessionStore.StoreAsync(ticket);
    var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(
        new ClaimsIdentity(
            new[] { new Claim(SessionIdClaim, _sessionKey, ClaimValueTypes.String, Options.ClaimsIssuer) },
            Options.ClaimsIssuer));
    ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, null, Scheme.Name);
}

var cookieValue = Options.TicketDataFormat.Protect(ticket, GetTlsTokenBinding());
```

When switching to a SessionStore, the session key is just added as a claim and then the cookie is protected.